# Python deduplicate list of Dictionaries by Value of a Key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a pretty basic (but not quite working) function to dedupe a list of dictionaries from key values by adding the key value to a list for keeping track.

```
def dedupe(rs):
    delist = []
    for r in rs:
        if r['key'] not in delist:
            delist.append(r['key'])
        else:
            rs.remove(r)
    return rs
```

Which gets used in the script just below on two lists of dictionaries:

```
from pprint import pprint

records = [
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:05:55', '00:07:54'],
                ['00:16:47', '00:20:04']]},
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:05:55', '00:07:54'],
                ['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:16:47', '00:20:04']]},
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:16:47', '00:20:04'],
                ['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:05:55', '00:07:54']]},
 {'key': 'Item 2',
  'name': 'Item 2',
  'positions': [['00:07:55', '00:11:23'], ['00:11:24', '00:16:46']]},
 {'key': 'Item 2',
  'name': 'Item 2',
  'positions': [['00:11:24', '00:16:46'], ['00:07:55', '00:11:23']]},
 {'key': 'Item 3', 'name': 'Item 3', 'positions': [['00:20:05', '00:25:56']]}
]

records2 = [
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:05:55', '00:07:54'],
                ['00:16:47', '00:20:04']]},
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:05:55', '00:07:54'],
                ['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:16:47', '00:20:04']]},
 {'key': 'Item 2',
  'name': 'Item 2',
  'positions': [['00:07:55', '00:11:23'], ['00:11:24', '00:16:46']]},
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:16:47', '00:20:04'],
                ['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:05:55', '00:07:54']]},
 {'key': 'Item 2',
  'name': 'Item 2',
  'positions': [['00:11:24', '00:16:46'], ['00:07:55', '00:11:23']]},
 {'key': 'Item 3', 'name': 'Item 3', 'positions': [['00:20:05', '00:25:56']]}
]


def dedupe(rs):
    delist = []
    for r in rs:
        if r['key'] not in delist:
            delist.append(r['key'])
        else:
            rs.remove(r)
    return rs

if __name__ == '__main__':
   res = dedupe(records)
   res2 = dedupe(records2)
   pprint(res)
   pprint(res2)
```

For either `records` or `records2`, I would expect to get:

```
[
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:05:55', '00:07:54'],
                ['00:16:47', '00:20:04']]},
 {'key': 'Item 2',
  'name': 'Item 2',
  'positions': [['00:07:55', '00:11:23'], ['00:11:24', '00:16:46']]},
 {'key': 'Item 3', 
  'name': 'Item 3', 
  'positions': [['00:20:05', '00:25:56']]}
]
```

But instead I get (for each of the two inputs):

```
[
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:05:55', '00:07:54'],
                ['00:16:47', '00:20:04']]},
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:16:47', '00:20:04'],
                ['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:05:55', '00:07:54']]},
 {'key': 'Item 2',
  'name': 'Item 2',
  'positions': [['00:07:55', '00:11:23'], ['00:11:24', '00:16:46']]},
 {'key': 'Item 3', 'name': 'Item 3', 'positions': [['00:20:05', '00:25:56']]}
]

[
 {'key': 'Item 1',
  'name': 'Item 1',
  'positions': [['00:00:00', '00:05:54'],
                ['00:05:55', '00:07:54'],
                ['00:16:47', '00:20:04']]},
 {'key': 'Item 2',
  'name': 'Item 2',
  'positions': [['00:07:55', '00:11:23'], ['00:11:24', '00:16:46']]},
 {'key': 'Item 2',
  'name': 'Item 2',
  'positions': [['00:11:24', '00:16:46'], ['00:07:55', '00:11:23']]},
 {'key': 'Item 3', 'name': 'Item 3', 'positions': [['00:20:05', '00:25:56']]}
]
```

I keep staring at and tweaking this, but it's not clear to me why it is not deleting the third instance if they are in sequence (`records`), or works for the one with three, but fails on the one with two if the one with three instances are broken up (`records2`).

Comment: Can you post your function?

Comment: it's in there, but have to scroll down, i'll edit so it's more clear.

Comment: where does `rs` come from in your function?

Comment: sorry, keep editing things i probably shouldn't. `rs` is just the list (fixed)

Comment: Don't remove from a list you are iterating over

Comment: @PadraicCunningham *extremefacepalm* gah, yeah. sheesh. i knew it was something obvious. Feel free to offer that as an answer if you want the points :)

Comment: You can use `reversed(rs)`. Work away with an answer yourself and you might get an upvote or two ;) Also `delist = {}` will be more efficient than using a list

Comment: `delist = set()`  not `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't remove elements from an iterator while iterating it.

Instead do this:

```
def dedupe(rs):
    delist = []
    new_rs = []
    for r in rs:
        if r['key'] not in delist:
            print r['key']
            delist.append(r['key'])
            new_rs.append(r)

    return new_rs
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham there you are not iterating rs, instead you are traversing a different object i.e reversed(rs) and removing from rs

Comment: That is fine unless you care about which dup gets removed, it is safe to remove when you start from the end